# Laravel displaying different data from select with the same column name with join statement

Tags: laravel-5

I want to ask how can I access to data in view when I have the same column names
for example:

```
  $sql = DB::table('kids')
    ->join('groups','groups.id','=','kids.group_id')
    ->select('groups.*','kids.*')
    ->get();
```

How to access to group select and how to access to kids select in my foreach loop?
Ordinarily I use for example $data->name but now I have two names (kid name,group name)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just alias the columns that have the same name:

```
$sql = DB::table('kids')
        ->join('groups','groups.id','=','kids.group_id')
        ->select(['*', 'groups.name as g_name', 'kids.name as k_name'])
        ->get();
```

Comment: Damn! Thank you so much I totally forgot that I can do that!